# Accessing a label created in the storyboard on current ViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, storyboard

I want to do something pretty simple but have yet am having a hard time doing so. I want to access a label created on the currently displayed ViewController (with storyboarding) from that view controller's class. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MobileOverlord is right, but you should really start using the Assistant Editor for wiring up things like this.  It will do ALL the work for you:

- Declaring your property as an IBOutlet
- Synthesizing it for you in the implementation file
- Setting it to nil in the viewDidUnload method (which you will forget 90% of the time if you do it yourself)

If you have never used the Assistant Editor, you should start it is super easy and helps you concentrate on more important stuff than manually wiring up your outlets AND actions.

Comment: If you can't get the Assistant Editor to provide the normal indicators while dragging over an interface or implementation, double check your view controller's "Custom Class".

Answer (score 3):

You need to make an IBOutlet Property in your viewcontroller.h and connect it to the label.

[image: Xcode Window]

After declaring the label property you can click and drag the o next to the property declaration (In Assistive Editor Mode) to the label to make the connection. Dont forget to synthesize it in the m.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize myLabel;
```